# Are these points mentioned anywhere in the Tanach regarding the Messiah?

Tags: tanach, messiah

There was some debate on [another question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/131499/) about whether there is an opinion that the Messiah has already come or not. That resulted in comments by James Read pointing out these four things that have not happened yet, presented as evidence that the Messiah has not yet come:

1. Returning the exiles including the 10 lost tribes.
2. Uniting the northern tribes with the tribe of Judah under one king from the house of David.
3. Building the temple.
4. Ruling over the world in a period of universal peace and disarmament.

So I'm looking for any mention in the Tanach of these four points, and in particular in connection with the Messiah's coming. Are these things mentioned in the Tanach in connection with the Messiah and what he has done/will do?

Comment: See for example Yeshayahu 2:2-4 And it shall be at the end of the days, that the mountain of the Lord's house shall be firmly established at the top of the mountains, and it shall be raised above the hills, and all the nations shall stream to it. ... for out of Zion shall the Torah come forth, and the word of the Lord from Jerusalem. And he shall judge between the nations and reprove many peoples, and they shall beat their swords into plowshares and their spears into pruning hooks; nation shall not lift the sword against nation, neither shall they learn war anymore.

Comment: @JamesRead that quote is not about the Messiah but about the end days

Comment: And when do you think we are expecting the Moshiach to arrive? If you are looking for explicit references to the Moshiach in TaNaKh you won't find them. Nowhere in TaNaKh is the Moshiach actually called the Moshiach. You have to rely on Jewish tradition for that.

Comment: You may want to also consider Yechezkel 37:22 And I will make them into one nation in the land upon the mountains of Israel, and one king shall be to them all as a king; and they shall no longer be two nations, neither shall they be divided into two kingdoms anymore. Who do you think that 'one king' will be? verse 24 says And My servant David shall be king over them, and one shepherd shall be for them all, and they shall walk in My ordinances and observe My statutes and perform them.

Comment: Regarding the rebuilding of the temple Yechezkel 37:26-28 says And I will form a covenant of peace for them, an everlasting covenant shall be with them; and I will establish them and I will multiply them, and I will place My Sanctuary in their midst forever. And My dwelling place shall be over them, and I will be to them for a God, and they shall be to Me as a people. And the nations shall know that I am the Lord, Who sanctifies Israel, when My Sanctuary is in their midst forever."

Answer (score 3):

The Tanakh has all that you mention and more concerning the Messiah.  It's all in Isaiah 9:5-6 and 11:1-13.  The Messiah will:

1. Be a human being. (It says: “For a child is born to us -- ki yeled yullad lanu”.)
2. Be a Jew descended from King David. (It says: “A rod from the stem of Jesse -- choter migeza' Yishai”.)
3. Deliver Israel from its enemies. (It says: “With the breath of his lips he shall slay the wicked”.)
4. Lead the exiles back into the Land of Israel. (It says: “And in that day... the Lord shall... gather together the dispersed of Judah from the four corners of the earth.”)
5. Rule and judge fairly. (It says: “With righteousness shall he judge”.)
6. Bring universal peace. (It says: “The wolf shall dwell with the lamb -- vegar ze-ev 'im keves venamer 'im gedi”.)
   People will stop bickering and envying one another. [It says: “Ephraim shall not envy Judah, and Judah shall not harass Ephraim.”]
7. Cause God to be recognized by all mankind. (It says: “The earth shall be full of the knowledge of the Lord -- mal'a haaretz de'ah et HaShem”.)

The Temple will also be rebuilt (since it was standing in the days of Isaiah).

Comment: #1 is incorrect. The more accurate translation is "a child HAS BEEN born" hence past tense. This verse is about Hezekiah whose rule was abundantly peaceful.

Comment: I think what OP is getting at is that none of these verses brought mention specifically the wording of "Moshiach".

Comment: @ezra No prophecies mention the word Moshiach when talking about the Moshiach.